# Store the text entered by the user as it is in the database C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to store the text entered by the user as it is in the database. Suppose if the user entered the text in proper case then the data should be stored in proper case in the database. If the user entered the text in upper case then the data should be stored in upper case and likewise. I am changing the textbox style property according to the user setting in the database. If the user setting is in proper case then using style i am setting the textbox property to title case and proper case likewise. But when storing the data the text is entered in lower case irrespective of the case in which the user entered.

```
CompanyMasterClass cm = new CompanyMasterClass();
    cm.strcompany_code = Request.Cookies["userinfo"]["companycode"];
    ResultClass objress = cm.fn_GetNameNumberStyle();
    if (objress.bStatus)
    {
        eslist<CompanyMasterClass> OBJLISTS = objress.objData as eslist<CompanyMasterClass>;
        if (OBJLISTS.Count > 0)
        {
            ViewState["namestyle"] = OBJLISTS[0].strname_style.ToString();
            if (OBJLISTS[0].strname_style.ToString() == "PC")
            {
                //txtGroupName.Text = "";
                //txtGroupSname.Text = "";
            }
            if (OBJLISTS[0].strname_style.ToString() == "UC")
            {
                txtGroupName.Style.Add("text-transform", "uppercase");
                txtGroupSname.Style.Add("text-transform", "uppercase");
                lblGroupName.Style.Add("text-transform", "uppercase");
            }
            if (OBJLISTS[0].strname_style.ToString() == "UG")
            {
                // txtGroupName.Text = "";
                //txtGroupName.Text = "";
            }
        }
    }
```

Here I am setting the textbox style according to the property set in the database by the user.

How to store the text entered by the user with the case in the database?

Thanks,

Comment: Come on, don't be shy, show us your code where the DB write is occurring.

Comment: Also mention what database you are using. No sensible database out there will automatically convert text to lower case. Have you seen the data directly in the database as opposed to reading it using your code? Maybe its stored in the right format in the db, but while reading, you are accidentally converting it to lower case...

Comment: I am converting the textbox style according to the user entered specification in the db and I also want to store the data according to the case in which the user entered.

Comment: Save the user input text as it is but convert/apply style while displaying it. I think OP wants to convert input text to *ProperCase* or *TitleCase*.

Comment: You also might considering sticking to naming conventions, it would make your code more readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The css style `text-transform` only displays the code in that way. 
It does nothing to the data entered by the user.

If you want to store the data as per this formatting, you need to transform in on the server before inserting.

The browser will not do this for you.

You have to write some server code like:

```
if (OBJLISTS[0].strname_style.ToString() == "UC")
{
    var myDbGroup = txtGroupName.Text.ToUpper();
}
```

Comment: But the user not necessarily write the data in the uppercase. He can also write in the lowercase or propercase. How to detect that?

Comment: Browsers give you the data as the user typed it. Even when you tranform it to upper case, at the server you will get it as the user typed it. CSS only displays the text as per the transform